# Variable length structure in legacy code snippet

Tags: c++, struct

I have been re factoring some legacy code recently and came across this

```
struct A
{
    struct B
    {
     ...
    };
    B member[0]; // Well known struct hack. Don't require any help here

   static int32_t Size(uint32_t count) return { (int32_t)(sizeof( A ) + count * sizeof( B[1]));}
};
```

I would require some help to understand the Size() method.

Why not just use `size( A ) + count * size( B )` ??

What's the use of `B[1]` ?

I don't understand why the question is down voted.
Link to the code running.

http://codepad.org/aGhQatEN

Comment: Sorry abt that. Renamed the variables.

Comment: What you posted doesn't have valid syntax. Make sure you post a credible example.

Comment: Are you sure it's not `member[1]`? `B` is a type, so `B[1]` doesn't make sense.

Comment: ^ That's exactly my question.Not sure what it means.

Comment: It would probably be better if you cut and pasted the _actual_ code, you're getting all messed up by trying to "simplify" it.

Comment: The downvotes are probably because you're not posting the actual code causing the problem.  There's an obvious typo in your final line.

Comment: And I would say that according to the standard `sizeof(B[1])` is illegal, and shouldn't compile.  (But both g++ and VC++ seem to accept it.)

Comment: what's the use of `B member[0];`?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc To prevent the code from compiling with a compliant compiler?  (This is a variant of the classical struct hack, which has never been legal, even in C.  But it _would_ work, provided the last array element had a size greater than 0.)

Comment: You *should* use a minimal code segment. We *don't* want to parse a big blob of code for you, but you should provide a minimal example that actually *works*. Which means it has to include `count`...

Answer (score 1):

Whatever `B` is defined to be, it is surely a pointer.

`sizeof(B)` will return the size of a pointer while `sizeof(B[1])` will return the size of the type of the elements `B` is defined to point to.

The following fragment will print `4,1` :

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main(int arg, char *argv[])
 {
   char *B;
   printf("%d,%d\n",sizeof(B),sizeof(B[1])); 
 }
```

Note that it is not undefined behaviour to reference `B[1]` as `sizeof()` works at preprocessing time.

Comment: First of all thanks. 

In the above code snippet, do u know how sizeof plays together with B[1] ? I think sizeof should be implemented by the compiler and should be macro. Correct ?

Comment: "Whatever `B` is defined to be, it is surely a pointer": in the code he posted, it was a `struct`.

Comment: And it's not undefined behavior, because `B[1]` is a type expression, an array [1] of `B`.  Even in a context where it would be evaluated (e.g. `new B[1]`), there would not be undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Having corrected for the obvious typos in your code...

The operand to `sizeof` can be either an expression, or a type
(which must be in parentheses).  In your case, `B` is a type, so
`B[1]` is also a type: an array of 1 `B`.

As to why the author wrote something so silly, rather than just
writing `sizeof(B)`, you'll have to ask him.  I've never seen
anyone do something like this.  (It might make sense if he had
written `member[0]`.  But not `B[1]`.)